# LGTM code analysis exclude file from analysis?

Tags: github

I am following the guide here https://lgtm.com/help/lgtm/javascript-extraction

to exclude my folder

here is my lgmt.yml

```yaml
extraction:
  javascript:
    index:
      exclude: 
      - folderA
      filters:
        - exclude: "**/*"
```

I want to exclude everything in folderA, but it is not working, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extraction:
  javascript:
    index:
      exclude: "folderA"
```

turn out this is working, it excludes everything in `folderA`